# Pandas - how to use value from variable(instead of variable name), as a column name when filtering?

Tags: python, pandas

How to force pandas to use value from variable and not the variable name itself while filtering?

Given:

```
column_name = "weird_name"
df = pd.DataFrame(data={column_name: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

returns:

```
    weird_name
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

now, I would like to filter the weird column, however usual way treats variable `column_name` as the name of column:

```
df[df.column_name > 3]
```

so obviously it throws:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name'
```

PS. I would be glad if a native english speaker edited the title to sound more natural.

Comment: The problem with df.column_name can occur when column_name contains a couple of words, e.g. there would be problem if the column name looks like 'column name', but it would be fine if there is no blank space or there is an underscore, such as 'column_name'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As @jpp poined out in comments, this is the correct answer:

```
df[df[column_name] > 3]
```

Comment: ...I found the pythonic-answer to similar problem while creating the pandas-question and it resolved my issue. However I decided to post it anyway - perhaps other people hit the same puzzle.

Comment: Eval is quite an antipattern here. Use brackets as usual. Attribute like access through dot is only available when the column name is a valid Python identifier.

Comment: `eval` is really not the conventional way to go about it - @jpp's recommendation is what you should be using.

Comment: @jpp I have used `df.column_name` patterns so extensively I forgot about brackets.... Thanks for reminding me. I have edited the answer.